# Is there a term for a proposition emphasizing the impossibility of an event?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

Propositions such as *When Hell freezes over*, *When pigs fly*, and *When chickens get teeth* are used to emphasize the impossibility of an event happening.

Is there a term for these expressions in the way that a terse statement of a general truth, such as “Power tends to corrupt, and absolute power corrupts absolutely," is an *aphorism*?

Comment: I see that you have cited Lord Acton's dictum. My own take on things, just in case anyone hasn't been tuning into Fox News of late, is that we are certainly living in interesting times to which I would append my own homespun polemic that true love almost always dies but money $$$ stays green for ever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may call them ***idioms of improbability***

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_idioms_of_improbability) says:

> There are many idioms of improbability, used to denote that something is impossible or unlikely to occur.